# Ethernet shield IP and Server with Different network

Tags: arduino, ethernet

requesting on your inputs on this please. Im having trouble interfacing my arduino ethernet shiel to my server where the PHP code to send the data to database save.

IP address assigned to ethernet shield is 192.x.x.x
while the server is 10.x.x.x

192 servers can ping to my 10 series servers but the ethernet wont connect to my server.

Meanwhile if I used this:

Ethernet IP = 192.x.x.1
Server = 192.x.x.20

I didn't face any problem interfacing my ethernet to my server.

My question is, does ethernet shield allowed with different networks use? Thanks.

Comment: I solved this myself. :) You just need to define all the network requirements.